# show a child div on radio click

Tags: jquery

I am trying to show a the corresponding div when a radio button is clicked but (this) doesn't seem to be working here?

http://fiddle.jshell.net/og3pz25q/

```
$('.thumb input[type=radio]').change(function() {       
   alert(this.value);
   $(this).find('.blurb').show();    

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` looks for child elements. Here element with class **blurb** is not the child of input, hence, it will not work. You need to update from

```
  $(this).find('.blurb').show();
```

to

```
 $(this).parent().find('.blurb').show();
```

For reference - http://fiddle.jshell.net/og3pz25q/1/

Comment: children of parent also called siblings. `.siblings('.blurb')` works as well.

Comment: @user3154108 - That is also an alternative. OP was using find, hence, wanted to answer in that direction only.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `find()` , since element with class `.blurb` is not inside `radio` tags.

Instead you need to traverse back to its parent element and from there traverse downward to find the element with class `.blurb`.

**JS CODE:**

```
$('.thumb input[type=radio]').change(function() {       
  alert(this.value);
  $(this).parent().find('.blurb').show();    
});
```

**Live Demo @ JSFiddle:http://fiddle.jshell.net/dreamweiver/og3pz25q/2/**